# Fill method in Laravel not working?

Tags: php, laravel

I am learning how to use Laravel framework but I am having troubles with filling a Model. Here is my code:

The model `Event`:

```
<?php
class Event extends Eloquent {
  //Some functions not used yet
}
```

And here is the code in the controller:

```
$event = new Event();
$event->fill(array('foo', 'bar'));
print_r($event->attributes);
```

So, why the `print_r` is displaying an empty array?

Comment: You can try use `$event->fill(array('foo' => '', 'bar' =>'' ))`. and use `var_dump` instead of `print_r`

Comment: Not working, but thanks @LLL!

Comment: Do you want print the store data? Because I found use `save()` after `fill()`. I ref this site http://jasonlewis.me/article/laravel-and-eloquent-part-1-basics

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> The **attributes** is a protected property. Use **$obj->getAttributes()** method.

Actually. at first you should change the model name from `Event` to something else, `Laravel` has a `Facade` class as `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event` so it could be a problem.

Regarding the `fill` method, you should pass an associative array to `fill` method like:

```
$obj = new MyModel;
$obj->fill(array('fieldname1' => 'value', 'fieldname2' => 'value'));
```

Also make sure you have a `protected $fillable` ([check mass assignment](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment)) property declared in your `Model` with property names that are allowed to be filled. You may also do the same thing when initializing the `Model`:

```
$properties = array('fieldname1' => 'value', 'fieldname2' => 'value');
$obj = new ModelName($properties);
```

Finally, call:

```
// Instead of attributes
dd($obj->getAttributes());
```

Because `attributes` is a protected property.

Comment: If you ever need the Laravel event facade and a model named "Event" you can now import as any name you like, for example: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event as LaravelEvent` imports the event facade as "LaravelEvent" and is merely just a local name change within the file. A good way to get out of name conflicts.

Answer (score 16):

Also make sure that the `$fillable` property is defined in your model class. For example, in your new renamed model:

```
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ['field1', 'field2'];
```

If you do not have either `$fillable` or `$guarded` defined on your Model, `fill()` won't set any values. This is to prevent the model from mass assignment. See "Mass Assignment" on the Laravel Eloquent docs: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent.

When filling the attributes, make sure to use an associative array:

```
$event->fill(array('field1' => 'val1', 'field2' => 'val2'));
```

A useful way to debug and check all your values:

```
//This will var_dump the variable's data and exit the function so no other code is executed
dd($event);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Use a key/value array in fill:

An example:

```
$book->fill(array(
    'title'  => 'A title',
    'author' => 'An author'
));
```

Answer (score 1):

In your model you need to have `protected $fillable = ['foo','bar']`;

Then you can do:

```
$event = new Event(array('foo' => "foo", "bar" => "bar"));
$event->save(); // Save to database and return back the event
dd($event);
```

The array key needs to be on the `$fillable`, as Laravel will effectively call:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value){
  $event->$key = $value;
}
```

Alternatively, you can write directly to a column name:

```
$event = new Event();
$event->foo = "foo";
$event->bar = "bar";
$event->save();
dd($event);
```