# Laravel 5 - Updating associated models using push()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, model-associations

I am trying to do this:

```
$volunteer = Volunteer::with('user')->find($id);

$input = $updateVolunteerRequest->all();

$volunteer->fill($this->fillFields($input));

$volunteer->user->fill([
    'email' => $input['email']
]);

$volunteer->push();
```

But `push()` method does not seem to work.

It throws the following error:

```
FatalErrorException in Model.php line 1463:
Call to a member function push() on a non-object
It worked in Laravel 4. Is there a new way of doing this in version 5? Or am I doing something wrong.
```

I checked `$volunteer` and it returns the model.

Comment: You might find the following answer useful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24303003/fill-method-in-laravel-not-working

Comment: Fill method is working in my case

Comment: @aBhijit I have updated my answer with a link to the pull request I just submitted to correct the issue. I don't know if it'll get accepted, but you can take a look at it for a current solution, or for more information.

Comment: @aBhijit My pull request was merged in, so if you update Laravel to the latest release, this issue should be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `push` method loops through all of the loaded relationships on the model and calls `push` on them, as well.  So, it isn't the `push` on the $volunteer that's failing, it is a `push` on a related model that is failing.

In Laravel 4, `push` has the following code:

```
foreach ($this->relations as $models)
{
    foreach (Collection::make($models) as $model)
    {
        if ( ! $model->push()) return false;
    }
}
```

In this code, if the relationship returned a NULL, there would be no error.  `Collection::make(NULL)` returns an empty array, so the foreach would never execute.  However, in Laravel 5, `push` has this code:

```
foreach ($this->relations as $models)
{
    $models = is_array($models) ? $models : array($models);

    foreach ($models as $model)
    {
        if ( ! $model->push()) return false;
    }
}
```

In this case, if the relationship is null, there will be an error, since `array(NULL)` returns an array with one entry: the NULL value.  So, the foreach loop will execute, and it will try to call `push` on the NULL value, resulting in your `Call to a member function push() on a non-object` error.

So, it looks like this is a bug in Laravel 5.

## Edit

It looks like the `push()` method was updated because of an update made to the Collection object. I have submitted a pull request to correct the issue. You can check out the pull request [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/6778), which also contains links to reported issues and other background information.

## Edit 2

My pull request was merged in, so you should be able to update your Laravel 5 to the newest version and the issue should be corrected.